# Count triplets with following constraint

Tags: algorithm

Given A,B,C and D we need to find the number of triplets (x,y,z) such that ((x xor y) or z ) ≤ D under the constraint x≤A,y≤B,z≤C where each of A,B,C and D can go up to 10^18.

Since the answer can be very large we need to output the number of triplets modulo 10^9+7.

Basic and inefficient approach :

```
i=0,j=0,k=0,ans=0

FOR (i<=A)

   FOR(j<=B)

     FOR(k<=C)

        if(((i^j)|k)<=D) ans=ans+1

print ans%1000000007
```

Obviously its very inefficient can their be some better way ?

Comment: I don't have any algorithms off the top of my head, but it might help to take  a different approach - for each value of `w <= D`, find the triplets where `(x  ^ y) | z) == w)`. Observing that, for any `a` and `b`, both of `a | b <= a` and `a | b <= b` are always true (i.e. the result of bitwise or is never less than either operand - at least if you assume unsigned values) may be of some use. Unfortunately, xor is a bit harder to reason about...

Comment: @twalberg - I think you meant `a | b >= a and a | b >= b`, or just `a | b >= max(a, b)`?

Comment: @IVlad Doh! You're absolutely right... I even wrote the converse out in words immediately after... Good catch, thanks!

Comment: Your pseudo code is very wrong. You need to check whether (i ^ j) | k ≤ D, not (A ^ B) | C ≤ D.

Comment: @gnasher729 in C++ xor is denoted by "^" and or by "|"

Comment: @gnasher729 Huh..dat was typing error sorry

Comment: So can you fix the code in your question?

Comment: Wait,  do you have to do this over i = 0, 1, ..., A, j = 0, 1, ..., B or over a given array?

Comment: @IVlad  over i = 0, 1, ..., A, j = 0, 1, ..., B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can solve the problem by breaking the numbers (x, y, z) into bits. As x, y, z <= 10^18, so there is less than **50 bits** per number.

So starting from first bit to 50th bit, we need to know four things

- Whether `x` less than A
- Whether `y` less than B
- Whether `z` less than C
- Whether `(x ^ y) | z` less than D

So, we have our function:

```
long totalNumber(int bit, boolean lessThanA, boolean lessThanB, boolean lessThanC, boolean lessThanD)
```

For each bit position, we just need to try bit 0 and bit 1 for each number x, y, z

```
    long result = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < 2; x++){
       for(int y = 0; y < 2; y++){
          for(int z = 0; z < 2; z++){
             //update lessThanA, lessThanB, lessThanC, lessThanD. This step is omitted.
             result += totalNumber(bit + 1, lessThanA, lessThanB, lessThanC, lessThanD);
             result %= MOD; //remember to take modulo of the result. 
          }
       } 
    }
```

For our base case, just return 1 if we reach bit 50th

```
if(bit == 50)
   return 1;
```

So, applying dynamic programming in this case, we have a table

`dp[bit][lessThanA][lessThanB][lessThanC][lessThanD]`

and the time complexity will be reduced to `O(bit * lessThanA * lessThanB *lessThanC * lessThanD)` which is ~ `O(50*2^4) = O(800)`

**Final note:** this type of problem occurs quite frequently in today programming contest. Take a look at [problem B round 1B Google Code Jam 2014](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/2994486/dashboard#s=p1) for one example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea to start. Pick a number r. If i ^ j = r, and i is given, what possible values are there for j? Hint: There is exactly one.

If you had only the condition 0 ≤ i ≤ A, that would make it easy to find the number of solutions to i ^ j = r. Now there are two conditions, 0 ≤ i ≤ A and 0 ≤ j ≤ B. That's a bit more difficult. Post the solution, and then we go on.

Solving this little problem takes the execution time down from O (n^3) to O (n^2), which makes it possible to solve for A, B, C, D ≤ 10^6 which would be impossible with your algorithm.

Comment: I don't understand. You left out the or, and it needs to be `<= D`, not `= D`... can you explain your idea in a bit more detail?

Answer (score 0):

Since the question involves bit-wise operations, let's think about a binary example:

```
x = ???????????????????

y = ???????????????????

z = ???????????????????

D = 1100000011001101010 (binary)
```

Let's assume we can create a method (perhaps combinatoric), call it `f(D)`, to count the ways bits may be combined to yield `D` exactly. Here's one way to consider the numbers that will be lower than `D`:

```
(1) Any number without the highest bit D has set: 
    _xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

(2) Any number with the highest bit D has set, but without the next highest bit D has set:
    10xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

(3) Any number with the highest bit and the next highest bit D has set, but without the 
    third highest bit D has set:    
    110000000xxxxxxxxxx

 And so on...
```

Each one of (1), (2), (3), etc. is a distinct opportunity for a combinatoric calculation of possible triplets, where the ways to yield the bits already filled in may be calculated with our previous method, `f`, and the `x`'s may be easily calculated as all possible combinations.